# Is it a good idea to install Windows 7 on an ultrabook, driver- and performance-wise?

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, drivers, performance

I recently acquired a [Samsung Series 9 Ultrabook](http://www.samsung.com/uk/consumer/pc-peripherals/notebook-computers/ultra-portable/NP900X3D-A01UK). I have been requested by the owner to install Windows 7 on it instead of Windows 8, which is pre-installed.

In terms of driver compatibility, is this a good idea? Googling drivers shows [Softpedia has what seems to be sufficient functional drivers](http://drivers.softpedia.com/dyn-search.php?search_term=NP900X3D&x=8&y=4). [Samsung's support site shows them as well](http://www.samsung.com/us/support/owners/product/NP900X3D-A01US), but curiously enough Windows 8 drivers are nowhere to be found.

In terms of speed optimization, is this a good idea? The computer would appear to have a 128gb SSD inside. Regarding custom-tailored software for speed optimization, could it exist?

Comment: Side question: Is Win8 significantly different, insofar as compatability or usage, that I should bother swapping it out for your average end user? (above-50 year old man).

Comment: If its just the UI, you could just install a shell replacement like classicshell or start8

Answer (score 1):

I would guess that the reason for only having Windows 7 drivers their, is because most Windows 7 drivers are compatible in windows 8.

If you want speed I would suggest to just stay with Windows 8 as they have optimized the speed in most ways, like the start-up.
But with a SDD installed, then you would still have a fast Windows 7 and for "normal" use, it would be just as fine.

If the end-user is used to Windows 7 and not very fond to changes, then install Windows 7. Windows 8 should be more user-friendly (windows phone/tablet -like interface), but again that depends on the user.